# Windows Update stalls on Azure B1ms VM

Tags: azure, windows-update, windows-server-2019

I've encountered this repeatedly on Azure B1ms (1 vCore, 2 GB RAM) instances running Windows Server 2019 Datacenter. After rebooting themselves during automatic windows updates, the VM fails to boot cleanly and stalls. Boot diagnostics show the spinning dots loader usually present during OS updates.

Azure Resource Health says the VM is Available, but as it is booting it isn't running any user code or websites, and RDP is inaccessible. A reboot immediately brings the system back up and available, it doesn't seem to need to complete any further updates.

Event viewer reports "The Update Orchestrator Service service terminated with the following error:
This operation returned because the timeout period expired.", followed by a long sequence of notices of services entering the stopped state. Nothing further until reboot intervention.

I can't find much information on this, which seems odd - surely others having been running Windows in this configuration? It's small, but a supported Azure configuration so I would expect something so fundamental to work. The VM has not been reconfigured wildly and is effectively a stock Azure Windows VM instance with IIS.

Answer (score -2):

The problem with B series VM's is that you loose all your burst credits when you reboot, so when you are rebooting from applying Windows updates you have no credit, so you are not getting 1vCPU, you are getting the base level which is 20% of that. You machine is probably hanging because all of that CPU is used for applying updates. You really only have 2 options:

1. Wait for the updates to complete, which could take a long time with that amount of CPU
2. Scale up the VM to a larger size when you apply updates, then scale back down again

Comment: If that were the issue, why would another reboot fix it? Wouldn't that zero out the burst credits yet again?

Comment: Yes, it would zero out the credits, so you need to scale up to a cpu size that has enough resource at baseline without credits to do what you need, or a non bursting cpu.

Comment: What I mean is, it won't restart the first time, according to you because it zeros out the credits. But the second time it does restart, despite supposedly also zeroing out the credits that time, too. Why is it different the second time if, according to your explanation, the same thing happens both times?

Comment: Really not sure I’m getting your point, by scaling up you are getting a more powerful VM that is able to complete the updates quicker, due to a more powerful CPU. If you scale up to a larger B series then you will have a more powerful base CPU even with 0 credits, so it won’t need to burst. If you use a non bird table SKU then you get the full CPU

Comment: In the question post, the VM reboots twice--same VM, same CPU. The first time is automatic and fails. The second time is manual and succeeds. Why does the manual reboot succeed even though the automatic reboot fails? If it were solely a matter of CPU power, then they would either both succeed or both fail, because the CPU didn't change.

Comment: I would guess the second reboot stops the current application of windows updates that were running, and they are marked as failed when it comes up again, so not actually applied.

Comment: Losing credits when you reboot only occurs if you completely 'Restart' the VM (such as in the Azure portal). If you reboot the VM itself using normal Windows functionality (such as Windows update) it won't lose credits.